# Ширина страницы js

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

Получаю некорректную ширину страницы в js скрипте. Приведу пример:
Скрипт в js файле

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  console.log(window.innerWidth);
});
```

Стиль в css

```
@media (max-width: 990px){
  body{
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

И типовой пустой скелет html документа.
Проблема проявляется следующим образом. Открываю страницу в devtools в "device" режиме. По одному пикселю уменьшаю ширину и смотрю вывод скрипта в Console вкладке. Начиная с 991px до 987px получаю такой вывод: на ширине 989px в браузере js выводит ширину 990px, хотя css стиль сработал правильно и закрасил все в красный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По итогу стили уже применились, а код, например, в if(ширина < 990) не сработает.
Пробовал вместо `window.innerWidth` поставить `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. Результат не изменился. Новичок в js и вебе в целом. Что я упускаю из виду?

Comment: мб какая нить ширина скроллбара вертикального мешает?

Comment: Я думал насчет скроллбара, но решил, что он на "постоянной" мешал бы и js каждый раз давал не тот вывод (Возможно я не прав). Но тут именно в одном месте затык. Конкретно баг на 989px, пока что. Я использую ширину 990px как breakpoint и хочу чтобы css и js одновременно срабатывали. По факту css сработает на 989, а js только на 988

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать не медиа запросы, а просто при достижении определенной ширины экрана менять класс у Body с помощью JS?

Comment: В целом это может помочь, я об этом не подумал. Просто стили с медиа я написал раньше чем js и хотел воспользоваться уже написанным.

Comment: Добавлю только что баг так же воспроизводится в пустом документе где нет вертикального скроллбара. Вариант с присвоением класса в js мне действительно сможет помочь, но баг не решает. Если не возражаете, по этой причине я не буду помечать комментарий как ответ.

Comment: @Vladimir, верно

Comment: А вот такой код возвращает целое значение или с дробной частью?  `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width` или `document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width`

Comment: @DiD оба варианта дают дробную часть. Их результат немного проясняет ситуацию. На 989px document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width выдает ширину 989.6000366210938. Видимо, window.innerWidth округляет такой результат то 990px, что и являлось "багом".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментарию [@DiD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1356532/%d0%a8%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-js/1356800#comment2407050_1356532), немного понял ситуацию. Если использовать для определения ширины:

```
document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

, то результат будет с дробной частью. Если уменьшать ширину экрана по 1 пикселю, то примерно каждый 4-ый пиксель будет с дробной частью > 0.5.

Судя по всему, `window.innerWidth` округляет это значение и выдает ширину на 1 пиксель больше фактического. Это и было "багом" описанным в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о "синхронизации" CSS и JS в плане использования соответсвтующих правил, то предлагаю через `CSS-variable` менять значение переменной, а в JS считывать это значение и реагировать соответствующим образом.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', checkWidth);
checkWidth();

function checkWidth() {
  console.clear();
  console.log(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--is-thewidth'));
}
```

```css
:root {
  --is-thewidth: moreThan990;
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  :root {
    --is-thewidth: lessThan990;
  }
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```